# The cells in a static table view are not resizing as soon as the view is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted the poster to have a fixed height and the rest of the contents should be sized dynamically. The 2nd and the 3rd section have the text whose size should be decided dynamically i.e should be decided based on the content of the text.

[image]

The contents are resizing only if the screen is scrolled for a minimum of 2 times. This is the code I wrote in the heightforrowat and estimated heightforat.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        return CGFloat(250)
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        return CGFloat(250)
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

}
```

Comment: add height of value greater than or equal to the label in cell or set line numbers to zero for UILabel

Comment: or ty setting default height for tableview in viewdidload like         tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0 and   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. It worked for me

Comment: I tried doing that too @Vinodh, but it dint work for me.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You shouldn't use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as a return value for `estimatedHeightForRowAt` and you should just instead return a fixed value.
2. Also you need to set the `numberOfLines` to 0 and `lineBreakMode` to `word wrap` for all the `UILabels` that have a dynamic height.
3. Make sure you have properly setup constraints for each of the `UILabel` for them to resize properly. I.e a top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint to its `superview`

Comment: Thanks @Rikh for your suggestions but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you try calling `reloadData` on `viewDidAppear` for your `UITableViewController` and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: That too dint work. I wonder if there is some bug with the simulator.

Comment: I'm curious about how you have setup the constraints for the label, maybe there in lies the problem

Comment: As the tableview i'm using is static, so I pinned the labels to the superview.

Comment: On all 4 sides i presume? And if all 3 points i mentioned are accounted for, I have no idea what could be causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's not working with default cell of `UITableViewController` . So instead of that i have created custom `UITableViewCell` with one title and description label with constraints. It works like a charm .

Please find the attached image for reference

[image]
Also please find the sample source code am using.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8rgab3x8eirp3q/SelfSizingDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: If the text is static i.e i write it on my own then it's working. But i'm getting the text from a server. The constraints you added in the storyboard are almost similar to that of mine.I was wondering if the problem is with the simulator.

Comment: Actually i'm running os x in vmware and i'm not able to connect my device i mean Xcode isn't detecting my device.

Comment: it won't work try archive it and install in device and check